# How to use custom UICollectionReusableView as section header of collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I've been driven insane for hours as I can't get around with the issue.

I have a collection view which can have different section with different no. of items in each. For each section I need to use a section header of different type. So for this, I'm going to use `UICollectionReusableView`. But I can't seem to succeed in using a custom subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` by means of `UINib` registration.

> A crash happens when I downcast the reusable view to my subclass. Like:

```
let friendHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, 
                                    withReuseIdentifier: "FriendHeaderView", 
                                    for: indexPath) as! FriendHeaderView
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private let viewModel = ProfileViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        // more code
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "FriendHeaderView", bundle: nil), 
                                forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, 
                                withReuseIdentifier: "FriendHeaderView")
    }
}
```

Now here is the data source implementation:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // valid implementation
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // valid implementation
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // valid implementation

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let friendHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "FriendHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! FriendHeaderView

            // *** Crash happens here *** //

            return friendHeader
        default:
            assert(false, "Invalid element type")
        }

    }

}
```

And I don't know why the `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` needs to be also implemented. So here it is:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 100)
        return size
    }

}
```

---

> Okay, now come to the point: The above mentioned crash doesn't happen
>   at all if I don't downcast with `as!` operator. Well, if I use section
>   header from the storyboard instead of `UINib` registration, there is
>   no crash.

If I'm going to need multiple type header, then I can't also use storyboard approach or without down-casting approach as I need to feed data to those headers.

---

**What can I do to have multiple type headers with view built from interface builder?**

---

I've made a [demo project](https://github.com/M-I-N/CollectionViewHeaderDemo/tree/master) with what I've said above. If anyone is interested please check out that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you assign proper class and identifier in your Xib file, then it will work without crashes.

Comment: Great. Actually that's it. But I think it needs a detailed answer for future readers coming with same problem. For this I'm adding another answer.

Comment: I was going crazy trying to figure this out!  Ha! yes this was it I forgot to set the class in the xib!  Thank you

Comment: Very helpful!!  Xcode doesn't add the subclass name in XIB created with "UICollectionReusableView".

Answer (score 2):

Well, after some more investigation and the input from @good4pc in the accepted answer (actually I found out that by myself before looking at the answer) it seems that the issue is actually happening for some unwanted issue with **Xcode**.

When we create any view (preferably, `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionViewCell`) with `.xib`, the class identity is provided automatically for that `.xib` in the identity inspector. But this was not the case for `UICollectionReusableView`. See the attached screenshot below for easy understanding.

### This is a `UICollectionViewCell` subclassed with `.xib`:

[image: UICollectionViewCell custom class]

### This is a `UICollectionReusableView` subclassed with `.xib`:

[image: UICollectionReusableView custom class]

---

> So the key is to provide the class identity of the `.xib` file which
>   is done from the *attributes inspector*.